How will Yarlung-Tsangpo dam affect India?
China has started building the Yarlung-Tsangpo River dam in Tibet, which is rumored to be much bigger in size than the Three Gorges dam.
How will it affect India environmentally in the future even if India takes all the measures it can take from within it's territory (e.g., building counter-dams, etc.)?
https://www.eurasiantimes.com/new-boiling-lac-chinas-constructing-of-worlds-largest-dam/amp/

this might be a good question if we can avoid politics and opinions when answering this question.
